# can not go other view by Search By date

Tags: asp.net, ajax, razor, controller, actionresult

I have a view (named searchForm) that contain input tag to picking time and search and show it in "other View Page" (searcheResultPage),
But i have a great problem that after calling method when i fetch values (List)  from db it doesnt go to the other view(searcheResultPage)?
Also i try to do that by passing data by redirect in controller between searchForm &  searcheResultPage,  but when i want to redirect to other view it doesnt pass fetched List and page will show empty?

first page

```
<div class="input-field col m6 s12">
   <input data-jdp id="date" type="text">        ==> data-jdp: for persian calendar
   <label class="contact-input" for="date">Date</label>
</div>

<button id="getArchiveWarm" class="waves z-depth-4 mr-1 mb-2"> searchForCars</button>
```

Controller :

```
    public ActionResult searchForm(DateTime fromTime, string driver)
    {
        var result = secondPage(fromTime, driver);
        return View(result);
    }

    public List<be.Dto.warmValuesDto> secondPage(DateTime fromTime, string driver)
    { 
        var result = _context.searching(fromTime, driver); <== it returns a List by 20 element
        return result;

    }
```

Jquery to Post Function :

```
 $('#getArchiveWarm').click(function (event) {
     $.post("/Main/searchForm", { fromTime: input0, driver:Name})
 }
```

secondPage

```
@model List<be.Dto.warmValuesDto>
 @foreach (var i in Model)
 {     <tr>
          <th>@(p=p+1)</th>
          <td>@i.WarmCarNumber</td>
          <td>@i.WarmCarDriverName</td>
       </tr>
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery will not redirect to the pag,so you can try to post the form to the action rather than using jquery:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="searchForm" asp-controller="Main">

    <input name="fromTime" />   //the input contains the value of fromTime 
    <input name="driver" />   //the input contains the value of driver

    <input type="submit" value="searchForCars" class="waves z-depth-4 mr-1 mb-2" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks friend, i did it, but because of value dataType (Datetime) it passed 0/0/0/ 0:0:0 to controller, persian calender has a lib that it makes process confusing! but i searched for other ways and find using ViewComponent alternatively to do!!